# Going into root using a text file in Kali

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I have got Kali-linux installed on my PC. Every time I restart i have to pass it some commands. I found a shortcut by writing all those commands in text file and executing the text file in terminal. However, that requires me to go into root mode using

```
sudo -i
```

and enter my password, which we suppose is:

```
^^^^^^^^
```

Now I want a procedure through which I'll just have to execute the program in terminal and it will get me into root mode i.e. it will enter password itself.

Somewhat like this:

```
sudo -i
^^^^^^^^
```

Like I don't even have to enter the password. Is there any way just double clicking a file and getting in root mode...?

Comment: Setup proper sudo permissions to run your file without authentication.

Comment: If you installed a newer version of Kali, there is not a "root" user (same for new version of Ubuntu). I have both Kali and Ubuntu VMs.  Once I start a flow of work, I only have to enter the password once. Not a big deal.

Comment: @John root is *always* there. It doesn't have a password set, which is another topic, but it is still there. For example, if you properly drop a public SSH key into `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, you'll be able to SSH to the machine directly as root with key even while there is no root password set (this is how OpenSSH is configured by default). And there is `sudo -s` which changes you into this "root mode" (gives you a root shell and `whoami` or `id` will say you're root). Don't confuse people with that "there is no root user".

Comment: "root" is hidden - just like Windows.  That is what I meant.  I never use it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to write a script which isn't using sudo and then run the script itself using sudo. So you'll enter the password once. Or even permit running it without password — see the next paragraph.

You may set up `sudoers` so it'll don't ask for a password for certain commands, which happen inside your script, or for running a script itself (e.g. `sudo myscript.sh`). Be **extremly careful** with this, because you essentially circumventing a protection `sudo` gives you; if *somebody* modifies your script, their modifications will be run as the privileged user! Better, of course, is to set up some file in the drop-in directory `/etc/sudoers.d/` rather that modify the master file (it'll get overwritten on package update, while drop-in files won't):

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/my-script
```

Read `man sudoers` for details on how to write this `my-script`.

Another way is to know sudo has "-S" command line parameter, which makes it to accept the password from the stdin. Then you put the password into the file, protect the file properly and you'll be able to cat it into `sudo -S`:

```
echo "pAs5w0rD" > cwfile
chmod 0400 cwfile
# the following is how to use this in the script
cat cwfile | sudo -S privileged-command
cat cwfile | sudo -S another-privileged-command
```

---

Having said all of that, I realized, that *any* of these solutions are inherently insecure.

So, if there are privileged commands you need to always execute on boot, think of creating a boot-time service which runs those commands for you during startup. This is not hard.